# Memory leak in StackOverflow on review tab, Chrome

Tags: bug, review, google-chrome

Not sure if someone is looking into this issue but in case you keep refreshing the `review -> first question` page on StackOverflow you will notice memory increase. I got more than 1GB used by stackoverflow 1 tab only.

[image]

**Steps to Reproduce:** As someone suggested that it is not reproducible on their machine, I tried to reproduce the issue and found it reproducible in new window of chrome.

To reproduce, goto `Review->First Posts` page not `Review` only and then keep pressing `F5` for sometime. Check windows task manager or chrome task manager. There is significant increase in memory used by tab. (changed from ~50mb to ~150mb in just 5-6 refreshes).

My machine config: Windows 7 (64bit), i5 proc, 4GB ram

**Additional details** I have configured chrome to reload last session tab on start (*not sure if helpful*). Also here is the complete chrome task manager capture (tried again to reproduce in new window and successfully reproduced):

[image: Reproducible Bug]

**UPDATE:** I tried to reproduce it on FireFox and it was not reproducible there. First memory goes up to 150MB but after that cleaned up again. Not able to reach even 170 MB. So seems like an issue with Chrome instead of stackoverflow.

Comment: Something's weird, but I'm not observing it when I hit the page - I only get 77MB usage on the page.  For comparison, I get 55K when I'm on this page.

Comment: Hmm... I am not sure what was the reason but I spent good time in analyzing which tab is culprit and found it is the stackover flow only. Previously it was around 800MB then refreshing page led to 1Gigs+

Comment: And most of the time I was refreshing the review page and reviewing the questions (on same tab)

Comment: I tried refreshing/reviewing and could not get the tab at more than 40MB (and lowest score is around 29MB). But still a weird problem.

Comment: Hmm, I seem to remember someone bringing up something similar on another Meta. Can't seem to find it.

Comment: What browser plugins are you using?

Comment: Adblock, Google Calendar, Google Dictionary, Google URL shortener, Chrome to phone

Comment: Would you try it in another browser?  A browser page doesn't persist data between refreshes.  It's more likely a Chromium bug.

Comment: @RohitKandhal Chrome has been developing memory leaks recently. I've moved away from it until they're resolved. That being said, I just looked into this with Firefox, and am not having memory leaks.

Comment: Will surely try.

Comment: @bobobobo What about session storage? That persists throughout your session

Comment: Session is just a single cookie identifier passed between the browser and the server on each request.  The session data however is stored on the server. [Apparently the max size of the cookie data is 4093 bytes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640938/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-a-web-browsers-cookies-key)